# Should I inform my employer of plans to get more visible tattoos?

Tags: professionalism, communication, appearance

A bit of background: I have one visible tattoo, directly on my hand. Since I've started my job 7 months ago fresh out of college, it hasn't been mentioned once.

Now, there are a lot of other tattoos I plan on getting. My one visible tattoo wasn't an issue during the interview process and obviously in getting hired, and I'm really unsure as to why. I'd like to think that they really don't mind tattoos, and it isn't even a considering factor for them. On the other hand, being in the deep south, I can't help but wonder if they chalk it up to me being "young and dumb" or something similar. Perhaps they think I'll only have this one.

I don't see any on anyone else I work with. As far as I know, there's nothing in their policy about it. I mean, I would think it's safe to assume such a thing given that I've been hired.

Personally, I'm of the opinion that if a workplace doesn't accept things like that, then I'll find another job. That's perfectly within their right. But I'm wondering how to approach this situation.

Is it the polite thing to do to inform my boss before it happens? Should I just come in with it and see what happens? My only concern with approaching my boss with it is that I don't want him to think it's up to him. If I approach him about it, it's really just going to be a formality.

Comment: "Personally, I'm of the opinion that if a workplace doesn't accept things like that, then I'll find another job." Sounds like a plan! What kind of job do you have?

Comment: Hah..yeah. I'm developing software right now.

Comment: And nobody else in the development team has tattoos? I'm surprised.

Comment: It's funny how your prejudice about southeners caused you to fear they will have prejudices about your tatoos.

Comment: How long have you worked there?

Comment: @user70848 "Since I've started my job 7 months ago"

Comment: "My one visible tattoo wasn't an issue during the interview process and obviously in getting hired, and I'm really unsure as to why". It sounds like you're a bit pissed they haven't made an issue out of your tattoo. Problem? :-) I work in Ohio at a pretty conservative employer, and when we've had guys with tattoos all the way from shoulder to wrist it hasn't been an issue. Still, if you're in a very conservative area it might be taken negatively. But I say ink. If you ink and they keep you, you're there for life. But if you tattoo and they toss you, it just wasn't meant to be. Best of luck.

Comment: @TheNettyProfessor You should probably [edit] your question to clarify that you're talking about arm tattoos. If you reference "visible tattoos" in a workplace and you've already got one on your hand, the only other skin that's always visible would be your face which is in a whole different ballpark from arm tattoos that might show up with short sleeves.

Comment: Are you speaking of the South of which country? Japan where if you have a tattoo you can't get into saunas?

Comment: Sometimes, people get shocked at very innocent looking things. Because, it is not about "you". It is about their "state of mind on that day". As an experiment, show up to office with little face painting (or plastic peelable tatoos) and study people's feelings.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but - you've been on the job for 7 months, fresh after college. Quitting it now would play against you during salary negotiations on your next one. You could also wait with your tattoo for 1-2 years, and then make it. If they choose to let you go, at least you worked there for some time, so it doesn't look bad on your resume.

Comment: 7 months in your first software dev job after college would not do much to hurt your resume.

Comment: @TomášZato Not sure how you inferred "prejudice about southerners" from the OP's question. Unless you think "deep south" implies some sort of prejudice.

Comment: What benefit do you hope to gain by telling your boss about your plans?  What good do you think will come of it?  If none, then don't do it.  This applies to pretty much everything.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Are you customer facing? If so, that could have a bearing on how they will receive it. Otherwise, I'd suggest go ahead and get it. It's dangerous to set a precedent of notifying them about something that has no bearing on your job.

I'm certain you've weighed the potential issues that visible tattoos may have on future employability but you probably wouldn't want to work for someone who had issues anyway.

I would also consider location of the new tattoo relative to the visible one(s) you already have. Going from an arm or hand to another one probably wouldn't be that big a deal. But going from arm or hand to face will have some shock value.

You might also wish to consider if you care whether this changes your relationship with people for whom you work.  They may see you differently and this could affect interpersonal relationships as well.

One suggestion I would make is to float some trial balloons.  Talk to coworkers about tattoos and attitudes casually. Mention that whatever you're considering might be something you might want. See their reaction and make your decision whether to "warn" them based on that. My feeling is that if **you** treat it like it's a big deal then they will too. If you treat it matter-of-factly, they may as well.

Lastly, I would encourage you not to stereotype everyone in the deep south with a broad brush. We're not all close-minded backward intolerant hicks. You'll find biases elsewhere in the country as well and you'll find that such biases are as individual as the people who hold them, not the region in which they live.

Comment: I'm not customer facing. However, I could be later in life. Who knows. That's irrelevant though. I definitely like your suggestion about trial balloons and about if I treat it like a big deal, they likely will too. And my apologies for implying that I thought that way about southerners. I come from a small town where the stereotype is actually the norm. But you're right in that I should avoid that.

Comment: The part about biases is pretty important here. Not only because generalizations are just that, general, but also because it's probably also exists in more places than you think.

Comment: When I moved to a southern state, I saw more tattoos than I ever had before.

Comment: One of life's occasions where it's better to ask for forgiveness afterwards, not permission beforehand.

Comment: And not that forgiveness is even necessary. OP is doing nothing against policy.

Comment: "We're not all close-minded backward intolerant hicks."  Damn straight. Some of us are close-minded backward tolerant hicks.

Comment: `future employability but you probably wouldn't want to work for someone who had issues anyway` That's a very short-sighted comment to make. Is having a visible tattoo soooooo important that if it precludes you from future employment, you really (I mean really really) don't care? You won't even know if the tattoo is the reason they didn't hire you - they just won't call you back. For customer facing positions in most industries, visible tattoos won't do you any service. In non-customer facing positions, tattoos in certain places (like the face) will have the same effect.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Not short-sighted at all. Some of us don't have to take whatever job comes along and prefer to choose working somewhere that fits our personalities and attitudes. It's widely known that "culture" is one of the most important considerations when deciding whether to pursue a position. A bad culture fit almost always predicts a bad employment fit as well.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep That is all true - but what's important to a 20 something year old fresh out of college probably won't be important to the same person 30 years later. That's the nearsightedness I'm pointing out, and there certainly is a plethora of folks who got tattoos while young that they wish they hadn't... Shutting doors today that you may want left open in the future, is usually not what one wants to do.

Answer (score 45):

I suggest taking the long term point of view. Someday, possibly in 10 or 20 years time, you may want a job for which visible tattoos would be a problem. I know at least one person who missed out on a job she would have really liked because of a tattoo. If she had known she would have that opportunity, and lose it because of the tattoo, she would have chosen a less visible location.

With suitable clothing choices, there are many places you can get a tattoo that can be hidden, if necessary, on-the-job, but visible during leisure time. Get your tattoos that way, and you are not eliminating any career choices.

Either way, there is no point telling your employer in advance, unless the employer's view will affect your decision.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question though. OP isn't asking about the advisability of getting a tattoo. That decision has already been made. The question is whether the employer should be told ahead of time.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I think the OP is the one who should be told ahead of time. The employer is basically a bystander.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Having seen someone lose out on a job she wanted and could have got with a more strategic tattoo placement, I'll give up some reputation to warn of the long term risk.

Comment: See? This really is a community. We care about people.

Comment: In 20 years time, you will likely have a US president who is a tattoo-covered ex-Hell's-Angel (if not indeed current member in good standing).

Comment: @Kaz Certainly possible, but so is a return to dress standards that would make any visible tattoo a deal killer for any job. If the OP wanted to get a purple with green polka dots hair job I would say "go for it", because that can be changed when necessary.

Comment: OP already has a visible tattoo that cannot possibly be hidden. This advice is good and worth considering for others faced with this choice but it doesn't apply to this particular situation.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Considering that tattoos are likely to be more permanent than jobs, it makes sense to consider future employment situations. In fact, I would say that how the current employer reacts is almost inconsequential.

Comment: @200_success I never disagreed with the advice. I'm only saying that it's not an answer to the question. Yes, this is a community based on votes so one can ignore the rules to give unsolicited advice if the community likes the advice.  That's what's happening here.

Comment: I disagree with this. While it should be considerd (long and hard!), it should not be the deciding factor. Using this logic you would do nothing risky, because you might get a scar, that recruiters might dislike or get kids for that matter. So not going to downvote as the advice is sound! But I disagree you should limit youself today, because in 10 or 20 years someone might disapprove (unless that someone might be yourself).

Comment: Upvoted because, while not necessarily the best answer, it gives reasonable and applicable advice. While OP may be set on a tattoo, the location and visibility of OP's new tattoo might be considered (a tattoo sleeve may be covered by a shirt sleeve, while a face tattoo would be more difficult to cover).

Answer (score 13):

Where are you getting the tattoo?  There is a large difference in perception of a tattoo on your forearm and one on your neck.

The best answer I can give you is, it depends.  It depends on the company culture where you work, the kind of boss and coworkers you work with and what your role at the company is.  They may be fine with someone who works in the warehouse having a tattoo but will never promote that person to a client facing role.

I had two tattoos that are in places where they are always covered, and decided that I wanted a power button on my wrist and was not sure how it would go over with my company and our clients since I was in a client facing role.  To evaluate it I drew the tattoo on my wrist everyday for 6 weeks.  When that time passed and no one mentioned it I went ahead and got it done.  It has not been a issue in the almost 10 years and 5 jobs later.

Comment: For now, I'm thinking just my arms. The neck could be a possibility under the right circumstances, but that would be quite far in the future, and even still unlikely. My role in the company is a developer and I don't ever interact with customers. I don't expect to stay invisible forever though. If I could draw worth a damn, I might give that a shot! Hah

Comment: @TheNettyProfessor I made a stencil by drawing it on a piece of cardboard and cutting it out.  Seriously if you are ok with it having a negative impact on your current workplace just go and do it.  Wear long sleeves if you are really concerned.  My only recommendation is dont get something stupid.  Cause you know I will make fun of someone for stupid tattoos.

Comment: _awkwardly shifts shirt to cover up tribal armband from when he was 19_

Comment: that's actually a really good idea I think, to repeatedly draw what it would be and see if anyone notices

Comment: I’m surprised it's not more common practice to get *draft* tatoos in henna first, not just to try it but also refine the design.

Comment: First sentence belongs in a comment on the question, now OP's response isn't visible for other would-be answerers.

Comment: Thank you @Lilienthal I forgot that when I was responding.

Comment: @JasonJ Normally I'd suggest editing the question to include the info but I got to this question pretty late and given that OP isn't entirely sure in his comment means I'd probably not do so in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Just stroll in with it, it's your body, there is no need to ask permission. You seem to be already aware that tattoos do have some negative connotations with some, that is just something you have to live with. People get used to them.

I'm heavily tattooed and have several that I couldn't hide if I wanted to, face, neck, forearm, hand and finger. People do look sideways at them, and it may well have been a deciding factor in jobs I have missed out on, but again, that's just the social price you pay. It is also useful sometimes.

If you're going to worry about things like that, don't get tattooed (they don't wash off). In saying that, it also depends on the actual tattoo, gang insignia isn't a great idea, and neither is anti-social tattoos or swear words. But if you're willing to live with the repercussions then go for it.

Comment: Yup, at the end of the day you make conscious decisions and accept the consequences. It's a two-way street though. If you don't like the policy and they are adamant to budge, then you can always find different, more accepting environment. If they are just being difficult and value your looks over you as a professional and your expertise (I know, naive, call me Corporate Cubicle Romantic) then well... If I were a customer and for example had problem with engineer sent on site to sort out any issues, I'd be mad to do so. Very mad.

Comment: @Cthulhubutt Once it's on, it's a fait accompli, there is not a lot they can do about it overtly. It's more likely to be a factor further down the career track for the OP.

Comment: @Khilisi That's true. I don't think it's the end of the world as some people would make you believe. You just learn to deal with it along the way as that kind of malarkey takes on many forms in organisations, tattoos are just one example. It helps me to think about it this way: some folk thing tattoos are trashy, I think that people at work who wear formal black trousers and brown shoes are like that to me. Most important is not to compromise on this, it's your choice, no matter whether someone likes it or not.

Answer (score 5):

If you get many visible tattoos, your boss will either (a) not be bothered, (b) slightly annoyed, (c) highly annoyed so it will affect your career, or (d) so annoyed you lose your job.

What difference can it make to tell your boss ahead? It makes a difference if he or she convinces you to not have a tattoo. It makes a positive difference if the boss is Ok with the tattoo but appreciates that you asked. It makes a negative difference if the boss advices you strongly against the tattoo and you still go ahead.

What difference can it make if you don't tell your boss? You might lose your job because your boss would have talked you out of it, but you didn't give him a chance. Your boss may be annoyed because it affects the workplace and you should have asked.

If you are having a tattoo no matter what, possibly better not to ask. If you could be convinced otherwise, better ask.

Comment: Or if the choice of design might be affected,  better ask.

Comment: I doubt it's a good idea to let a permanent design for your body be altered by the wishes of someone you work with temporarily. You'll probably regret being forever stuck with a tattoo that isn't exactly what you wanted more than you'll regret losing that job 5 years ago because your then-boss didn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned the employee handbook. Policies like this are typically regulated by HR and the hiring staff. If there isn't an employee handbook portion (or even an employee handbook) about visible tattoos then there is no legal recourse the company can take against you.

If you were hired with a visible tattoo with no questions regarding it, chances are your boss is tattoo friendly.  I wouldn't put them in a potentially awkward situation in an effort to put your own mind at ease. I've always been a "it's better to ask for forgiveness, than to ask for permission" type of person myself.

Lastly, this really isn't a matter that deals with your boss. If you have questions about tattoos talk to HR about it, they will tell you real quick about the policies currently in place regarding the matter.

Comment: Perhaps you need to reread the question.  There wasn't a question about policy. It's about the advisability of telling the boss. There is no policy, that's been established because of the existing tattoo on hire.

Comment: Added additional information to my answer. Also it might have to do with policy since it is not directly stated that it doesn't. Checking the employee handbook before doing something is **always** advisable.

Comment: Our employee / student handbook clearly says "No visible tattoos". If it is not in the handbook (yet) they must not have a position (until someone causes them to take one).

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask your boss.

The situation is, your boss might not like it but accept it.

If you ask your boss and you get that answer and go ahead with the tattoo, you just did something you knew your boss didn't like. Your boss will think: "hey even if I told him I didn't like it he still did it."

If you don't ask, your boss still might not like it but think more like : "hey, he got another tattoo, I don't like tattoos, but he's a good guy and I never told him I don't like them."

It's better to ask for forgiveness then permission.

Comment: "It's better to ask for forgiveness then permission" -- provided you're prepared for what happens if you aren't forgiven. Since the questioner says that letting them know would be a formality, and is perfectly happy to leave the job in preference to not getting the tattoo, they probably figure that being fired (or asked to quit in order to avoid being fired) is not a problem for them.

Answer (score 1):

So if your current tattoo is obvious and conspicuous, and you haven't been doing anything to hide it, and no one has commented about it at all after this time - to me that is an implicit acceptance of your tattoo.

I don't think you are under any obligation to get permission for another one, as long as you aren't getting tattoos someone could find offensive like naked women, certain symbols, or words.